# Array is.Array if and else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I wanted to write a `if else` statement where if `Array.isArray` is false, display a message. The function I have below allows user to enter an address, click `Find ZipCode` and does it thing. The function works, it just that if I input an invalid address, it doesn't show the message I wanted, which is `invalid zipcode`

In my HTML, I have:

```
<label>
Address:
      <input name="address" type="text" id="address"></label>
      <input type="button" value="Find ZipCode" id="find">
<p id="output"></p>
```

and Javascript:

```
var hello = function(data) {
    var result = ""; // empty string to hold the value
    var address = $("#address").val();

    if (! Array.isArray(data))
    {
        $("#output").html("invalid zipcode");
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
            var zipcode = data[i].zipcode;
            result += address + " zipcode: " + zipcode;
        }
    $("#output").html(result);

    }
};

$("#find").click(function(){
    var address = $("#address").val();
    $("#output").html("Loading...");            
    $.getJSON("zipcodelookup.php", "address="+address , hello);  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you modified the `Array.prototype` there is no `Array.isArray` method. I think what youre looking for is `$.isArray`.

Comment: [ES5 adds an `isArray` method to `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). The noticeable exception to browsers which *don't* support this is IE < 10, however, it can be trivially polyfilled.

Comment: +1 `$.isArray` is definitely what the OP had in mind (or should use) since jQuery is already imported.

Answer (score 0):

You could also test like this to see if it's an Array:

```
function isArray(arr) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.apply(arr) === '[object Array]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing for types in Javascript to infer other conditions is often a bad idea. It seems that in this case, if the zip code is found, then an array (of something) is returned.

You are therefore concluding that if you don't get an array, the zip code wasn't found. That isn't particularly robust, it would be better for the server to return a defined message or error code that was more helpful, e.g. it could advise if the zip code wasn't found, the input was invalid or the database isn't available.

You can also do tests on the returned array to see if it has the features you want (i.e. use feature detection).